# needs right div on top

Tags: css

hello
I cant get the div on the right to be on top just like the div on the left:
http://katastar.free.fr/Document1.php
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this CSS for your right div:

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
width: the width;
height: the height;
```

Comment: then adapt the left one to: position: absolute: top:0; left:0;

Answer (score 2):

As you are floating left and floating right, you should swap your divs around like this http://jsfiddle.net/bgh3D/

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix for you would be to switch places (in your markup) between the content div and the right div, so that it would be:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right">right</div>
<div id="content">content<br><br><br><br><br></div>
```

It seems like you want to produce a three column layout, there are many css-techniques for this purpose, which one you choose depends on your needs (fixed/liquid width, column equal column heights etc), you might also want to consider putting your content div first in your markup to provide easy access to your content for mobile browsers etc.

Ther are plenty of examples/tutorials online you can check out. As an example, have a look at http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/.